indentation after pipe with a meta-function
I have a meta-function that is usually used more generically (i.e., not piped), but when doing quick/interactive work I often pipe it directly. I'd like the indentation to look like this:
fun(args, args, args)(args2) |>
  filter(...) |>
  ...

But Emacs/ESS indentation defaults to indenting this like
fun(args, args, args)(args2) |>
                      filter(...) |>
                      ...

I've looked at ess-arg-function-offset-new-line and related but haven't found a way to make indentation follow the first block above. Am I outside the realm of easy indentation?
